# How do you change Neovim's directory to the directory within a terminal session? Can this be done using a key map?

Tags: lua, neovim

I work within Neovim's own terminal session; in fact, my development work is done completely inside of Neovide. However, I have to use `:cd` to change Neovim's directory to match the directory within the terminal session; I'd like for this to be automated.

I've tried the following, but nothing works so far; the directory just gets changed to the home directory each time.

I tried to use `vim.fn.getreg("+")` to read the `+` register where the copied value is stored and then I tried to pass this `string` value to the `vim.fn.chdir` function, but for some reason, this does not work.

Note that the function `vim.fn.getreg` seems to return a string value with extra characters at the start and end.

```lua
local tnoremap = function(lhs, rhs)
  vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("t", lhs, rhs, { noremap = true })
end

tnoremap("<C-d>", 'pwd|pbcopy<CR><C-\\><C-n>:lua vim.fn.chdir(string.lower(string.sub(vim.fn.getreg("+"), 1, string.len(vim.fn.getreg("+"))-1)))<CR>')
tnoremap('<C-d>', 'pwd|pbcopy<CR><C-\\><C-n>:cd <C-r><C-o>+<CR>')
```